# Google Analytics: Track user from opening email to following link to finishing form

Tags: google-analytics, email, links, marketing

We track the opening of our marketing emails by using the `utm.gif` image which works well. But, we would like to see how many users go from opening the email, to clicking a link within the email and then complete a registration form.

Is it possible to track this sort of user flow and know how many users followed this path from the email?

Comment: Nik can you please share some information how you track the opening of marketing mails by using the utm.gif?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this is one of the tracking requirements what the [Google Analytics URL Builder](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867) tool is designed to help you address.

Set your campaign to reflect the mailing and generate a URL (the `utm_` variables in the GET string won't change, so it's fairly easy to programmatically add them to outoing newsletters if you'd prefer not to use the URL builder for every link).

Comment: But then when I am looking in Analytics later how would I see these results and the users who followed this path?

Comment: You would use an [Advanced Segment](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033017) to filter traffic by the campaign variables you want to observe (e.g. "campaign medium = email" or "campaign source = newsletter").